# Mirror Rig System

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]

I created a sophisticated hand rig system with constraints - rotation, scale, action, and also drivers. I wanted to mirror this system on the other hand and was faced with the problem of losing important parameters from the aforementioned constraints and drivers. Is there any way to mirror the rig system without losing parameters?

PS: For example, the recorded actions are not related to the copy in any way, and therefore the constaint action does not work anymore, the drivers simply disappear when copying.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure, I would try making a new save (just in case), making sure all of your bones are specifically named, i.e middlefinger1.L and this allows the computer to know to copy it. Then once you've done this with all of the hand, select the hand bones, right-click and press symmetrise. This should work but it can be fidgety. Hope this helps and good luck, the model looks great! :D